# Relative path issue on deployment server in AngualarJS app

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

In my Visual Studio project I have the following hierarchy:

```
index.html
/Images
/Scripts
/App
    /login/login.html
    /page1/page1.html
```

`login.html` and `page1.html` are partial pages that are rendered inside a ui-view div on index.html page.

On both login.html and page1.html I have some images to which the path is specified in the following way:

```
<img id="img1" src="../../Images/img_1.jpg">
```

It works fine, but when I move the application on the server where I am hosting it, the image is not found even though directory structure is the same.

What i have to do on the server is to change all paths to `"Images/img_1.jpg"`, then it works.

So if I do not change anything, the app is looking at:

> http://server3/Images/img_1.jpg.

And the image is really in

> http://server3/myproject/Images/img_1.jpg

On my dev machine the image path shows up at

> http://localhost:61777/Images/img_1.jpg

so clearly on the server it translates to

> http://server3/Images/img_1.jpg

I have tried fixing an issue of image not being found by changing the path in ng-error (onerror):

```
<img id="img1" src="../../Images/img1.jpg" ng-error="SetPath(this, 'Images/img1.jpg')">
```

my javascript

```
 function SetPath(el, path) {
    el.src = path;
 }
```

So I would not have to do that manually, but it does not work, the javascript does not get called.

Can anyone suggest a fix that works?

One thing is I cannot reconfigure app in IIS on my machine as I do not have access to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app translates image path from `index.html` base path so :

On server : `http://server3/myproject/../../Images/img_1.jpg` is translated to `http://server3/Images/img_1.jpg`

On your dev machine : `http://localhost:61777/../../Images/img_1.jpg` is translated to `http://localhost:61777/Images/img_1.jpg`. It works because your app isn't in a subfolder.

If you put `<img id="img1" src="./Images/img1.jpg">`, it should work in both environments.